# what is the difference between nested table and object type in oracle?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have following object tables in oracle DB.

```
create type deposit_ty as object
(
    depno number(6),
    depcategory ref depcategory_ty,
    amount number(6),
    period number(2)
);

create type deposit_ntty as table of deposit_ty;

create type address_ty as object
(
    homeno number,
    street varchar(30),
    city varchar(30)
);

create type customer_ty as object
(
    cusid char(4),
    custname varchar(40),
    address address_ty,
    dob DATE,
    deposits deposit_ntty
);
```

can any one tell what is the difference between column `address` and `deposits` in customer_ty object table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An object type/abstract data type/record is like a row or tuple: it contains an ordered set of attributes.  To populate `address` you must set one and only one value for each of `homeno`, `street`, and `city`.

A nested table is like a table: it contains an unordered set of rows.  Usually a nested table only contains a set of simple values, like a number.  In your example, it is a set of object types.  To populate `deposits` you can create any number of `deposit_ty`.

For example:

```
declare
  customer customer_ty :=
    customer_ty(
      'ABC',
      'Name',
      address_ty('123', 'fake street', 'Springfield'),
      sysdate,
      deposit_ntty(
        deposit_ty(1, null, 100, 1),
        deposit_ty(2, null, 200, 2)
      )
    );
begin
  null;
end;
```

Also, you probably want to use a `VARCHAR2` instead of `VARCHAR` or `CHAR`.  And if it's not too late, throw out all this object stuff and use tables like everyone else.